# Preview ringtone on selection in preferences

Tags: android, media-player, ringtone

I have this in my settings menu for picking a notification sound:

```
<RingtonePreference
        android:key="notifications_new_message_ringtone"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_ringtone"
        android:ringtoneType="notification"
        android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound" />
```

It works fine, but when you pick your sound it doesn't play it as a preview, and I don't know if it's possible to be done.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I did exactly the same thing and mine previews the sounds as expected. It might vary by Android version. (I'm on API 19.)